# D: print number of current month instead of its name

Tags: datetime, d, datetime-format

I need to get number of current month instead of getting its name:

```
void main()
{
    SysTime dt = Clock.currTime();
    writeln(dt.month);
}
```

The output is:

```
oct
```

but I need `10`. How I can get it? I found only one solution `cast` it to `int`, but is there any better way, or it's ok?

Comment: This happens because `writeln` calls `toString` for all provided values.

Comment: Can I prevent it to calling `toString`?

Comment: I'm sure that you can't and don't actually want to. (Well, you can pass a string to it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for explicit conversion as the Month enum's type is *int* by default (check more about [enums](http://dlang.org/enum.html)).

```
import std.datetime;

// Month is an enum - http://dlang.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#.Month
Month month = Clock.currTime().month;
int monthnum = 0 + month; // works
```

Comment: `to` does not perform an explicit conversion between `Month` and any numeric type ex. `int`. It performs an implicit conversion, because `Month` and `int` returns `true` when passed to the `isImplicitlyConvertible` template. `0 + month` looks rubbish and should be avoided. `to` is definitely the correct way to go about this. You can check it yourself with `isImplicitlyConvertible!(Month,int)` which returns true. Downvoted for that reason.

Comment: Who was talking about `to`? Enums have been used (and maybe you rightfully think - abused) like that for decades... `0 + month` was given as example that such operations are possible too. It should be easy to understand that `int monthnum = month;` works as well.

Comment: Also, why would I check whether Month can be implicitly converted to int?? - We all know it is! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std.conv.to()`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.to) for converting types.

This seems to work:

```d
import std.conv;
import std.datetime;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    SysTime dt = Clock.currTime();
    writeln(dt.month.to!ushort);
}
```

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need it for printing then use `writefln` like below.

```
writefln("%d", dt.month);
```

If you need to use the number then the `to` template can be used, which in general should be used for conversions.

```
writeln(dt.month.to!size_t);
// or ...
writeln(to!size_t(dt.month));
```

Ultimately you can also cast it.

```
writeln(cast(size_t)dt.month);
```